# Tradução do nome do esquema de cores do flair "hotdog"

Tags: debate, tradução

Cada esquema de cores tem um nome, mas apenas um foi traduzido, o Flair "hotdog" que passou para "carrinho de cachorro-quente":

[image: Flair Clean] [image: Flair Dark]

[image: Flair Default] [image: Flair hotdog]

Na minha opinião, acho que a tradução do nome do esquema de cores é errado.
Esse nome é utilizado para indicar à API como queremos obter Flair:

[image: Captura de tela]

Como se pode ver nas instruções para a construção do URL.

---

Se vamos traduzir os nomes para cada esquema de cor, como é que fica a interação com a API? Vamos indicar `theme=hotdog` quando o esquema de cores se chama "carrinho de cachorro-quente"?

Por outro lado, será que a StackExchange vai mesmo estar a aceitar os nomes dos esquemas de cores em várias línguas para poder servir todos os sites que venham a surgir?

Answer (score 1):

Na realidade mesmo em inglês o nome do tema não corresponde à url: **"theme: hot dog stand"**. Na minha opinião, o que falta é traduzir "default" (não temos por aqui um nome próprio para *clean* nem *dark*; "limpo" e "escuro" são adjetivos comuns, que não remetem aos estilos em particular - normalmente referidos através de seu nome em inglês mesmo).

A alternativa de não traduzir nada, sei lá, acho que acaba com a piada... (ALGUÉM USA o tema hotdog pra alguma coisa?!) A não ser que se coloque "tema: carrinho de hot-dog", pelo menos os brasileiros que assistem a novela das 9 vão achar ainda mais engraçado...

Quanto à URL, imagino que todos os sites continuarão a usar palavras-chave em inglês mesmo, mas isso é com a equipe do SE. Talvez caiba uma indicação que qual corresponde a qual, mas talvez seja exagero (afinal, não é como se tivessem 200 temas pra escolher...).

Comment: Eventualmente podem-se traduzir os nomes, quanto mais não seja pelo motivo que mencionaste "_acaba com a piada_". Mas essencialmente acho que ou se traduz tudo ou não se traduz nada, umas coisas em Inglês e outras em Português é que é mesmo "matar o ceguinho"! :)